# How to get 1st field of AJAX response when name changes depending on url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an AJAX call to an open library of books.  When I make the call, the data comes back like so:

```
{"ISBN:0261102303": {"bib_key": "ISBN:0261102303", "preview": "noview",
"thumbnail_url": "https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/8447430-S.jpg",
"preview_url": "https://openlibrary.org/books/OL26793280M/Lord_of_the_Rings",
"info_url": "https://openlibrary.org/books/OL26793280M/Lord_of_the_Rings"}}
```

The ajax call is as follows:

```
var isbn = $(list).attr('isbn');
    if(isbn == "null"){
        document.getElementById("cover").style.visibility = "visible";  
    }
    else{
        var coverUrl =  "ISBN:" + isbn;
        a=$.ajax({
                    url: "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" + isbn + "&format=json",
                    method: "GET"
            }).done(function(data) {
                try{
                     //data.?????
                }
                catch(err){
                      alert("err");
                }
            }).fail(function(error) {
                    $("#listResults").append("An error occurred while loading cover");
            });
    }
```

The issue is, is that the object that is returned is not a static name, but depends on the variable "isbn" that is inputted for the link.  Since I cannot do "data.ISBN:0261102303.thumbnail_url" because the ISBN: could be followed by any random numbers, how do I access the thumbnail_url for all possible AJAX calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `thumbnail_url` property using the `isbn` variable that you are passing to the ajax call like:

```
const url = data[`ISBN:${isbn}`].thumbnail_url;
console.log( url )
```

If you need to access full `ISBN:*` object then you can do:

```
const obj = data[`ISBN:${isbn}`];
console.log( obj )
```

DEMO (using `fetch()`):

```js
(async() => {
  const isbn = '0261102303';
  let response = await fetch("https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" + isbn + "&format=json");
  let data = await response.json();
  
  const obj = data[`ISBN:${isbn}`];
  console.log(obj)
  console.log(obj.thumbnail_url)
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```